# CSS: How do you inspect the settings for text you are highlighting/selecting with your mouse or keyboard?

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I'd like to inspect the mouse/keyboard text highlighting/selection in my browser, but don't know how to inspect it. I need to inspect it so I can change it. I'm working [on my website](https://gabrielstaples.com/ydotool-tutorial/) using this theme (https://github.com/mmistakes/minimal-mistakes) as the baseline, and the text highlighting is currently black, as you can see here:

[image]

So, how do I inspect and change this property in my CSS?

I've `grep`ed my repo for `cursor`, `mouse`, `user-select`.

I've googled a lot and can't seem to find out what property I should be changing.

I've asked here too: https://github.com/mmistakes/minimal-mistakes/discussions/4392

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this in the theme you were using:

```
::selection {
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
}
```

The file name is here:

https://github.com/mmistakes/minimal-mistakes/blob/8a67ce8e41ec850f2d7c373aa47739b2abfee6f1/_sass/minimal-mistakes/_reset.scss#L40

You can override this by setting this CSS content:

```
/* Selected elements */

::-moz-selection {
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
}

::selection {
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
}
```

to your desired color.

Comment: Thank you. What is `::-moz-selection` vs `::selection`?

Comment: `::-moz-selection` is used for firefox browser. When people are using firefox browser, it might not work if you just used `::selection`

Answer (score 1):

Your issue pertains to the selection/highlighting of text in your browser, which can be manipulated in CSS via the `::selection` pseudo-element.

This can be found in the Chrome DevTools, as shown in the image below (the selection is in orange):

[image]

For more information on how to utilize and manipulate this [pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements), you can refer to the documentation on the Mozilla Developer Network (MDN): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::selection

I hope this helps resolve your issue!

Comment: Thanks! On Stack Overflow itself, I tried to find this `Pseudo::selection` element and can't find it. On my website I can find it just fine though. Why? Can you find it on Stack Overflow?

Comment: I figured it out. On my website, my CSS settings have set `::selection` properties. On Stack Overflow, Stack Overflow has not, so my system uses the browser's default selection settings, and the inspector shows no `Pseudo::selection` element at the bottom at all.

Answer (score 1):

### Change text highlight settings for a website in your browser: all about the CSS `::selection` (and legacy Firefox `::-moz-selection`) elements

Both answers thus far are very useful. [I marked an answer correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76499824/4561887), but I'd like to provide more more detail.

I've learned that the file [`_sass/minimal-mistakes/_reset.scss`](https://github.com/mmistakes/minimal-mistakes/blob/master/_sass/minimal-mistakes/_reset.scss#L33-L43) contains these lines which format the mouse/keyboard selected/highlighted text:

```css
/* Selected elements */

::-moz-selection {
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
}

::selection {
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
}
```

Color `#fff` is the same as `#ffffff` and is all white, and `#000` is the same as `#000000` and is all black. Those numbers are for red, green, and blue values, in that order, in hex.

This page [given to me by @Cody Chang](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76499784/4561887) is very useful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::selection. Read it in full. Read here too: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements.

In the "Browser compatibility" section in the first of those links, if you click on "Firefox" in the table, it will expand and you'll see this:

[image]

This image shows that Firefox as of version 1 ("Released 2004-11-09") has supported `::selection` only "with the vendor prefix: `-moz-`". As of version 62 ("Released 2018-09-05"), Firefox has provided "Full support".

This means that the `::-moz-selection` element in the CSS/SCSS code above is specifically for Mozilla Firefox version 1 through 61, and version 62 or later should use `::selection` instead. I just tested this on my system with Chrome, and Firefox version **103.0**. If you set both, the `::-moz-selection` setting will be ignored, and only `::selection` will take effect in both Chrome and Firefox. In other words, `::selection` always takes precedent, even in Firefox. Since we are so far past Firefox version 62 now, there's probably no point in keeping `::-moz-selection` at all anymore, but it's there for compatibility reasons in the unlikely event someone is still using Firefox version 61 or earlier. If you have only the legacy `::-moz-selection` element and not the `::selection` element, then Firefox will use the `::-moz-selection` element, and all other browser's will use their default settings only, since they only look for `::selection`, and it is unset.

I also discovered through testing that these values are to *override* the browser's default selection settings. If I just comment them out, I get the look I actually want!--the normal browser default settings in both browsers:

1. **Chrome:**

   [image]
2. **Firefox:**

   [image]

That looks so much better in my opinion, so I'll just comment out both completely!

Lastly, I discovered, with some help [from @Cody Chang](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76499784/4561887), that the `::selection` Pseudo-element *is* shown in the inspector on both Chrome and Firefox, but *only when you have manually set a `::selection` (or in Firefox only, a legacy `::-moz-selection` works too) element!*

So, if you have *not* set a `::selection` element override, it will *not* show up in the inspector at all, and the browser will just use the default color schemes, which is what I recommend anyway.

Here is a screenshot of the `::-moz-selection` pseudo-element showing up in the Firefox inspector when I had set only the legacy `::-moz-selection` element, for testing, and *not* the `::selection` element:

[image]

Again, these pseudo-element settings will *not* show up in the inspector if you have not manually overridden them by explicitly setting them in your CSS.